# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'app1.myUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

In my Django project, I have an `app1` named app.

I create a model named `myUser` in my `app1` app's **models.py** like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser

class myUser(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    roll = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
```

I also set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in **settings.py** like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app1.myUser'
```

Here, `admin.site.register(myUser)` is also done in **admin.py** and `app1` is also installed in `INSTALLED_APPS` list in **settings.py**. Now I have face following error in my console when I use **migrate** or **runserver**:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'myuser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 156, in get_user_model        
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 210, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 180, in get_model
    raise LookupError(
LookupError: App 'app1' doesn't have a 'myUser' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run      
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "G:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Project\django\hackathon practice\prjct1.1 User model\app1\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 20, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "G:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 160, in get_user_model
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'app1.myUser' that has not been installed
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you open django shell with `python manage.py shell` and run `from django.apps import apps` 
`apps.all_models['app1']` and share the output?

Comment: python manage.py shell Give error, like..... KeyError: 'myuser'

Comment: have you created the model in the `model.py` file or `models.py` file? It should be `models.py`

Comment: It is in models.py

Comment: @Kanchon Gharami comment out `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app1.myUser'` in `settings.py` and execute those commands in the shell.

Comment: @Adithya that gives the following output:

{'tablea': <class 'app1.models.TableA'>, 'myuser_groups': <class 'app1.models.myUser_groups'>, 'myuser_user_permissions': <class 'app1.models.myUser_user_permissions'>, 'myuser': <class 'app1.models.myUser'>, 'student': <class 'app1.models.Student'>}

Comment: how have you added it to `INSTALLED_APPS`? have you used an `AppConfig` to register?

Comment: @Adithya I had added app1 in INSTALLED_APPS. But I hadn't use AppConfig to register. I have only use admin.site.register(myUser) in my admin.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that occurs has the following source:

```
File "D:\Project\django\hackathon practice\prjct1.1 User model\app1\models.py", line 3, in <module> from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
```

Don't import the UserCreationForm before you declare the User in your model.py! You can either have a new file forms.py or import the UserCreationForm after you define your user in your model.py.